# vertex cover polytope has integer vertices for bipartite graph?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, linear-programming

The vertex cover polytope of a graph $G$ is the collection of all the vectors $x\in \mathbb{R}^{|V(G)|}_{\ge 0}$ such that
for all $e=\{u,v\}\in E(G)$, $x(u)+x(v)\ge 1$.

It is known the dual of it, say the [matching polytope](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-433-combinatorial-optimization-fall-2003/c17fffb9e0d47d41ef84f9b922ca18e3_l5.pdf) of bipartite graph has integeral vectors as the vertices. I am wondering is it possible to prove the same is true for the vertex cover polytope, i.e., if $x$ is a vertex, then $x(v)$ is 0 or 1?

Comment: Yes, and the proof is the same. The transpose of a TU matrix is TU.

Comment: I understand how to use the unimodular matrix method to prove it as the second proof in the reference https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-433-combinatorial-optimization-fall-2003/c17fffb9e0d47d41ef84f9b922ca18e3_l5.pdf I am wondering is it possible to prove it by the disturbing weight method (the first proof of the reference)? For edges, one can say they form a cycle. But what about vertices?